# Название таблицы и заголовки из БД на русском

Tags: php, html, mysql

Нужно вот что сделать.
Имеется информационная система с возможностью создавать новый журнал/справочник, которые представляют собой таблицу. Ну потом она должна выводится как таблица на страницу со всеми данными и названиями столбцов и с названием самой таблицы. Но обычно же это всё прописывается в самом коде, а не в бд. Вытащить из бд название таблицы с названиями столбцов наверное можно, но они все на английском.
Как можно подобное реализовать?

Comment: записать в другую таблицу названия столбцов на русском?

Comment: Но вообще вы даже конечно не понимаете, в какую петлю лезете, с этим "создавать новый журнал/справочник".

Comment: *обычно же это всё прописывается в самом коде, а не в бд.* Обычно как раз метаданные хранят в БД и используют при форматировании вывода.

Comment: Ну да, наверное у всяких умно-продвинутых всё так и происходит. Мы же на уроках все названия таблиц и столбцов (на русском) прописывали в коде, а из бд только данные столбцов вытаскивали.

Comment: то что вам нужно - это EAV. Но предупреждаю, что там есть свои подводные камни